# Stange material/mesh glitch in LookDev mode

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, faces

Whenever I go into LookDev mode with this Cynder model I ported from SFM (which was originally an .mesh.ascii file) a strange graphical glitch occurs where I can see faces glitching through each other.
[image]

This was more obvious in edit mode.
[image]

In rendered mode it is completely fine, so I don't know what's going on. Because the faces show through each other in edit mode I'm thinking there's something wrong with the mesh but I'm not sure what.

[image]

I have many other models that I've imported from SFM into Blender the same way and they've never had this problem before.

Help would be gladly appreciated, please respond asap.

[EDIT]
Blender file below:

[image]

Comment: Heve you check if there is overlaping faces ? Did you recalculated normals ? Did you remove custom edge split ?

Comment: There are no overlapping faces and recalculating the normals didn't appear to do anything. What is meant by custom edge split and how do I remove it?

Comment: Seeing your edit mode screenshoot, i don't think it come from that, but you can see what it is here : https://i.imgur.com/NVCdlF5.png

Comment: Another thing you can look for is the clip start and end in the view of N panel https://i.imgur.com/IAnBRsE.jpg

Comment: I've also tried that, it didn't seem to work either. It just changed the boundaries of what could be viewed. I'm at a complete loss as to what could be going on with this.

Comment: Can you upload the .blend file ?

Comment: Uploaded the file, hope you can find what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your material blend mode is set to alpha blend, changing it to opaque fixes the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have that option in my material settings. Would it be because I'm in Cycles? https://imgur.com/a/EPkzZXh

Comment: Look dev uses eevee settings, switch to eevee, to change the setting then switch back to cycles.

Comment: I hope that this paper-cut of the lookdev and cycle ui inconsistency will be resolved in the new blender updates.